# Where does rsync send files?

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync

I wanted to send a file to server by using:

```
rsync -avz myfile username@151.161.10.10:~/tmp
```

However, I forget to give the destination folder, just typied:

```
rsync -avz myfile username@151.161.10.10
```

I cant find it under '/' or my userfolder.

Where did this file go?

*Ps. There are too many files on the server, so searching myfile by name takes forever...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You now have a (lokal) copy of `myfile` named `username@151.161.10.10`. Since the destination did not specify a valid remote location (user@hostname:file) or existing local directory, it was interpreted as a filename.